# Chinese Garbled in REPL in scala

Tags: scala, cjk, read-eval-print-loop

When I type in chinese characters in the REPL, only question marks are displayed, as in my second screenshot. How can I fix this? My scala version is 2.9.0.1 and OS windows

[image: before input the Chinese: 中国 using 搜狗输入法]

[image: after input]

[image: Can't display the Chinese word correctly]

Even if I start REPL with a property `-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"`

Comment: I want to input Chinese through REPL, but I got unreadable thing

Comment: If your question is "When I type in chinese characters in the REPL, only question marks are displayed, as in my second screenshot. How can I fix this?", then please say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, you're on Windows. I don't think this is supported at the moment. I some idea of what's going on. See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4711 for the investigation.

The root of the issue is:

1. jline2 (its jansi dependency) loads a DLL that uses some variant of 8 bits `getc` to read characters at the console and does not support double byte characters. The API call that could be used instead is `ReadConsoleInputW`.
2. The REPL output printing uses the underlying Java `System.out` which does not print unicode characters reliably - although your first snapshot in your question seems to imply that it works<sup>*</sup>.

I'm not part of the Scala team, but I tried to fix it and I may have something working more or less. See https://github.com/fusesource/jansi-native/blame/master/src/main/java/org/fusesource/jansi/internal/WindowsSupport.java (based on `WriteConsoleW` and `ReadConsoleInputW` and other additions in the REPL `ILoop` source - the changes are somewhere in [my fork](https://github.com/huynhjl/scala-full) on github - not updated in a while.

If you are interested, I may be able to provide an experimental fork of the 2.9.0.1 scala-compiler.jar and jline.jar and you could tell me if it works.

<sup>*</sup>*What is the code that prints `:1: xx 2:xx 3:xx 4:x 5:x` where x is some chinese character?*

Comment: At the bottom line of the first screenshot there is some Chinese words that come from IME(Input Method Editor). If you want to input Chinese word, such as 中国，亚洲, you have to do with IME.

Answer (score 5):

You must tell the REPL that you want to use unicode (or whatever encoding). Try

```
scala -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

when opening the REPL.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But unfortunately it make no effect.

Comment: Hmm, this usually helps on Unix systems. Unfortunately, I don’t know if it should work on Windows as well.